# Add Textbox at the cursor position in a table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to add, via VBA in MS Word, a Textbox at the current cursor position.

This works but if the cursor is located within a table (whatever cell), a Textbox gets added in the wrong location.

```vb
Sub AddTextBox()

Dim oShape As Shape
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

'get Cursorposition
x = Selection.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
y = Selection.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
    
Set oShape = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextBox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=x, Top:=y, Width:=200, Height:=12)

With oShape
    With .TextFrame
        With .TextRange
            .Text = "TEXT"
            .Font.Name = "Segoe Script"
            .Font.Size = 10
            .Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
        End With
        
        .MarginBottom = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.15)
        .MarginTop = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.15)
        .MarginLeft = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.1)
        .MarginRight = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.1)
        .WordWrap = False
        .AutoSize = True
    End With

    .LockAnchor = False
    .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapNone
    
    .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
    .Line.Visible = msoFalse
    .Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.8)
End With
End Sub
```

How do I place the TextBox at the cursor position, when the cursor is placed in a table?

Answer (score 1):

When you add a shape the position defaults to being relative to the margin, so you need to set the required relative position after you have added the shape.

```
Sub AddTextBox()

    Dim oShape As Shape
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long

    'get Cursorposition
    x = Selection.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
    y = Selection.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
    
    Set oShape = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextBox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=x, Top:=y, Width:=200, Height:=12, Anchor:=Selection.Range)

    With oShape
        .LeftRelative = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
        .TopRelative = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
        .LockAnchor = False
        .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapNone
    
        With .TextFrame
            With .TextRange
                .Text = "TEXT"
                .Font.Name = "Segoe Script"
                .Font.Size = 10
                .Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
                .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
            End With
        
            .MarginBottom = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.15)
            .MarginTop = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.15)
            .MarginLeft = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.1)
            .MarginRight = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.1)
            .WordWrap = False
            .AutoSize = True
        End With
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .Line.Visible = msoFalse
        .Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.8)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Fritz - if this has answered your question please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: The lines .LeftRelative / .TopRelative does not help in my case. The Textbox does not get positioned more precise to the cursor position. Nevertheless the option Anchor:=Selection.Range helped partly to reduce the issue. Thanks

Comment: @Fritz - `Selection.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)` does not give the cursor position. In a table it returns the position of the left edge of the cell. In a line of text, it returns the left of the line. That is as precise a location as you will get.